# numpy array shape change / extend

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to figure out how to change an array such as:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
a.shape
(3,3)
```

into:

```
a = np.array([[[1,255,255],[2,255,255],[3,255,255]],
[4,255,255],[5,255,255],[6,255,255]],
[7,255,255],[8,255,255],[9,255,255]]])
a.shape
(3,3,3)
```

essentially turning a single element `1` into a `[1, 255, 255]`

I've played around with `reshape` but I can't seem to get the logic to do this without a slow `for` loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to create a new array of the desired shape, filled with `255`s using [`np.full`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.full.html), and then to just populate the index 0 value of each of the inner lists with the values from `a`.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
b = np.full((3, 3, 3), 255)
b[:, :, 0] = a
```

Output is

```
array([[[  1, 255, 255],
        [  2, 255, 255],
        [  3, 255, 255]],
       [[  4, 255, 255],
        [  5, 255, 255],
        [  6, 255, 255]],
       [[  7, 255, 255],
        [  8, 255, 255],
        [  9, 255, 255]]])
```

Comment: that's absolutely spot on, thank you so much and for the fast reply!